# Splitting the date and time into two lines in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

I am getting the date and the time as one property in an object fetched from the database. I am also using moment to reformat the date and the time and here is the part that is implemented :

```
<td colSpan={1}>{moment(item.pickup_date).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')}</td>
```

I am trying to do something to show the date in a separate line and the time in a separate line too. How can we achieve this in javascript?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, you could use `split` function by splitting date string in comma.
Something like:

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a').split(',')[0] // to see date
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a').split(',')[1] // to see time
```

Of course this is just an example. You could try to initialize a var with moment time formatted and the on `td` apply the split function.

**EDIT**

@RobG made an intersting observation on comment and I think is useful to add it to the answer. The way I suggested infact does not use all the library potentiality. Infact, moment provides the possibility to format date by inserting a `br` tag in format itself. So, you can do also in this (very efficient) way:

```
moment(item.pickup_date).format('MMMM Do YYYY[<br>]h:mm:ss a')
```

Comment: Ciao @RobG. Yes it's a good point. I saw your solution in comment and I thought that was so smart that I decided to add it to my answer as a better solution. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

First show one value, then a line break, then the other value:

```
<td colSpan={1}>
  {moment(item.pickup_date).format('MMMM Do YYYY')}
  <br/>
  {moment(item.pickup_date).format('h:mm:ss a')}
</td>
```

Or to reduce the usage of `moment()`:

```
// earlier in the code, before the JSX rendering:
const pickup_date = moment(item.pickup_date);

// then in the code shown in the question:
<td colSpan={1}>
  {pickup_date.format('MMMM Do YYYY')}
  <br/>
  {pickup_date.format('h:mm:ss a')}
</td>
```